# Detecting the region between two straight lines

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have over 1000 images of the one attached below.

[image]

I need to extract the handwritten part only from these images. The size of the typed area varies a lot and so does the size of the handwritten part, so I cannot extract based on a fixed pixel value for row and column like  `img = img(300:1800,200:1600)`

But the handwritten part is always between the two straight lines, so one solution I was looking into was to somehow detect the lines in the image and then extract the region between the lines.

I tried following the tutorial here: http://www.mathworks.com/examples/image/mw/images-ex64995063-detect-lines-in-images-using-hough which uses hough transform to detect the lines, but I am not getting the results expected.

I first tried it on the original image

```
edg1 = edge(img,'canny');
```

but got a very noisy result.

[image]

So I tried converting it to logical and then trying again.

```
img_bw = im2bw(img,graythresh(img));
edg2 = edge(img_bw,'canny');
```

but even then the lines were not detected as expected.

[image]

Am I going on the right path? Is this the best way for me to extract the handwritten part from the files?

If so then how can I ensure that the lines are detected and I get the coordinates of those lines.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of the information is in the code comments but here is a brief outline:

I did some preliminary image cleaning using morphological filters (I'm sure a gaussian filter or similar would prove just as effective)

My approach was to some how use the row information to find lines. Think of taking a single column and plotting the pixel values. The lines (or any black text) should be easily visible in this format. So I took the average of the entire row and used that profile to assist in finding the lines. Since a line goes across a row all the values will be low and produce a strong peak. The characters have lot of white space so the row average should contain more white pixels therefore the peaks won't be as well defined

The final assumption is that the two largest peaks in this profile (starting from the bottom of the image) should be the lines.

Unfortunately, I did some empirical analysis (guess and check) for two parameters and they may require modification

1. `st_size`the size of the structuring element used for image cleaning. If all images are nearly the same size this does not need modification. Even though it isn't automatically determined, this is no different than using a smoothing filter of set size, so this shouldn't cause too many issues
2. `mask_thresh` the value used to find peaks. This could present issues with other images. The criteria was that it was lower than the `bot_lin_loc` but higher than the peaks of the handwritten text section. I simply made it 1/3 of the largest peak **This is the weakest link in the algorithm and may require more tuning on your end**

```erlang
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mO1S.jpg');
gim = rgb2gray(im);
[im_h,im_w] = size(gim);

%this is a quick attempt to remove background noise, the goal is to remove
%all the letters, and what you are left with is background
st_size = 10;
st = strel('disk',10);
im_background = imdilate(gim,st);

%now we take the difference between our background and original image
im_foreground = abs(im_background-gim);

%reduce the image to a row average to find lines
rowavg = mean(im_foreground,2);

%peak threshold (unfortunately this was determined empircally,I'm not sure
%if it could easily be automated)
mask_thresh = max(rowavg) / 3;
masked = rowavg > mask_thresh;

%finds the peaks using the values over the threshold (this is sort of like 
%non-maxima suppression)
potential_peak_idx = find(masked);
[~,peak_loc] = findpeaks(double(masked));

%at this point we assume the two "lines" closest to the bottom of the image
%are the lines that outline the text
bot_lin_loc = peak_loc(end);
top_lin_loc = peak_loc(end-1);

    %% plots results
figure(1)
subplot(2,2,1); imshow(gim); title('bw input image');
subplot(2,2,2); imshow(im_background); title('background image');
subplot(2,2,3); imshow(im_foreground); title('foreground image');
subplot(2,2,4); 
   imshow(im); 
   hold on
   line([0,im_w],[top_lin_loc, top_lin_loc],'color','g')
   line([0,im_w],[bot_lin_loc, bot_lin_loc],'color','r')
   plot(rowavg,(1:1:numel(rowavg)),'color','b')
   hold off
   title('annotated image');

figure(2)
plot(rowavg); title('row average')
hold on
grid on
scatter(peak_loc,rowavg(peak_loc))
line([0,im_h],[mask_thresh, mask_thresh],'color','g')
hold off
legend('rowavg profile','peaks','peak threshold')

%this is just a large version of subplot 4
figure(3)
imshow(im); 
hold on
line([0,im_w],[top_lin_loc, top_lin_loc],'color','g')
line([0,im_w],[bot_lin_loc, bot_lin_loc],'color','r')
plot(rowavg,(1:1:numel(rowavg)),'color','b')
hold off
legend('top loc','bot loc','row avg')
title('annotated image');
```

and image processing code is worthless without pictures, so here are the results

[[image: subprocesses[1]]
[image: rowavg plot]
[image: annotated results]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to process one step further before detecting the edges. You could try to make a projection along the x axis. This can be done by just iterating through the rows and summing along the individual rows.
Then you get peaks where text and lines are. You can then detect the lines by simply selecting the thinner peaks of the lines.